# Add attribute to gridcolumn xtype in extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid, and I need to add an attribute to the TD of the grid cell (not the header, the cell in the grid itself). It will probably be the same text at the column header, so I'd like to just define it in the `gridcolumn` xtype when I'm creating my columns. In doing some research I've found a `tdAttrs` config which I think would help, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it. Can anyone offer some pointers? If that's not the right direction to be looking, please let me know as well.

Also, I need this to be added to ALL the `gridcolumn`s in my application, so would I need to add an override for `ext.grid.column.Column` or put it somewhere else?

Comment: Not sure of your question if it is related to style of the column use tdCls http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-tdCls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do that is by adding `renderer` to column definition:

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    metaData.tdAttr += ' new-attr="new-value"';
    return value;
}
```

It requires you to define renderer for each column definition.

You can do it automatically by overriding `renderCell` in `Ext.view.Table`.
Try something like this:

```
renderCell: function(column, record, recordIndex, columnIndex, out){
    var origRenderer = column.renderer;
    column.renderer = function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
        metaData.tdAttr += ' new-attr="new-value"';
        return origRenderer ? origRenderer.apply(this, arguments) : value;
    }

    var result = this.callParent(arguments);
    column.renderer = origRenderer;
    return result;
}
```

Basically this code is switching renderer before calling original `renderCell` implementation. I don't see any other option.

Comment: OK, that's what I was thinking. I think I will have to go with the override, as then I'll be able to set a config value when creating the gridcolumn. And I already have renderer's set for half of my gridcolumns, so the override will help me not have to edit every renderer everywhere.